# Find $\limsup_n x_n$ and $\liminf_n x_n$ of $x_n=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

By trying I have found, that the sequence is falling and I'm fairly certain that it's going to $0$ for large n. So we know that $\liminf=\limsup=\lim$.
But how do I show that the sequence converges to $0$? Also is my argumentation correct so far?

Comment: The standard way? Multiply top and (missing) bottom by $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$. Either that or note that $\sqrt{n+1}\lt n+\frac{1}{2n}$. (Square this to show it.)

Comment: $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$

Answer (score 4):

By multiplying by the conjugate we have

$$x_n=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$
can you find the limit?

Comment: awesome, yeah it's obviously 0 at this point, thanks a bunch.

Comment: you're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

We do this by multiplying $x_n$ by its conjugate, expressing the numerator as a difference of squares, and then taking the limit of the result:

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{1}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt{n}}\\ \\
& = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n+1 - n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\\ \\ 
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} \\ \\ & = 0\end{align}$$

The rest follows as you argue. Since the limit of $x_n$ is $0<\infty$, as $n\to \infty$, the $$\liminf x_n =\limsup x_n =\lim x_n, \;\;n \to \infty$$

Comment: This one needs a TU too +1